# Description attribute on Enum giving error

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting the following error from the description attribute as follows:

> Attribute 'Description' is not valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'method' declarations.

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    [Description("Property 1")]
    Property1,
}
```

I have never had this error before and Google isn't shedding much light. I guess it is a reference issue, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: http://blog.waynehartman.com/articles/84.aspx check this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DescriptionAttribute` can be applied to virtually any type of member, including enum values. Are you sure you're using the right `[Description]`? Make sure you reference the assembly it comes from:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

And, if you do happen to have two different attributes called 'Description' in your scope, prefix it with the namespace to remove the ambiguity, i.e.

```
enum MyEnum {
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Blah")]
    MyValue
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It turns out that Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting also has a Description attribute. Thanks!